# Validity of limit of a function at the suprenum or infimum of domain

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let us assume a function $\ f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$ (The function is continuous in this domain).

Does  $\lim: \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exist?

The definition of limit of a function is:
[image]

By this definition, the limit does not exist as$\ f(a)$ is not defined as $\ a$ is not within the domain.

My reasoning for the limit existing is as follows: Since the limit can be found at $\ x = 0 + \phi $ , where phi is any real number greater than$\ 0$. Now let phi tend closer and closer to$\ 0$ and let $\ s_n $ be the sequence that stores all the values of these limits. If this sequence has a limit, then this implies that the sequence "tends" to this value. Is this not sufficient to state that the function should also tend to a value as $\ x \to 0 $ ?

I understand why the limit cannot be defined for any value which is greater than the suprenum or lesser than the infimum as the denseness of $\ \Bbb {R} $ allows for an infinite number of values between the boundary element of the interval and the suprenum/infimum.

However, if my above resoning is true(or atleast on the right path), then this definition could be extended to any arbitrary interval and thus a limit should exist for at least either the suprenum or the  infimum of the interval (except when the interval is $\ (-\infty,\infty)$ ).

Answer (score 1):

First: limits can be computed for accumulation points of the domain, and these are actually the only points where it is meaningful to compute them, if you have a continuous function (roughly speaking: if you know $f(a)$, you know for free how $f$ behaves locally).

Existence of your limit depends: if you take $f(x)=x$ and you restrict it to $(0, + \infty) $, then the limit exists and it is $0$. If you take $f(x)=sin(\frac{1}{x})$ which is $C^{\infty}((0, + \infty)) $, the limit approaching $0$ does not exist.

I think you still need some thinking on the definition of limit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the limit could exist and be different to $f(a)$ or even if $f(a)$ is not defined. If the limit exist and also is equal to $f(a)$ then you have continuity, but both things could be independent.
In your case since $f$ is defined strictly for positive values the limit cannot exist, because the limit existing requires two limits to exist, the limit $x\to 0^{+}$ and the limit $x\to 0^{-}$. The only that could be computed is the first, but the second one cannot because $f$ does not take values for $0-\epsilon$ for $\epsilon>0$